# cordova phonegap - How to use android API level 21

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin, cordova-cli

Hey I forked the push notification plugin (https://github.com/alexislg2/PushPlugin) and added it to my project.

The project won't compile with `cordova build` because I have a `error: cannot find symbol` error.

The reason is that I use in the plugin `Notification.setCategory()` method which is Android SDK 21.

How to force cordova to compile using API level 21?

I installed the android 21 sdk build tools + I set `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />` in my config.xml

But cordova keeps trying to compile with android 19. What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the progress of Cordova updating to android-21, android platform plugin v4.0 will support lollipop:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8026

There is an issue about cookie and a temporary workaround:
http://tol8.blogspot.ca/2014/11/fixed-apps-cordovaphonegap-targeting.html

I would suggest waiting for the next version, looks like 3.7.1 also updated the target api level.

I am not using cookie related feature in my project, so I just replaced "android-19" with "android-21" in

```
platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties
```

And adds preference in config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />
</platform>
```

Another workaround (but ugly) is change the system cache of android plugin code:

```
~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/framework/project.properties
```

---- Update ----

A better way of updating platform plugin will added in Cordova 4.2.1 (currently 4.1.2):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8239

```
$ cordova platform add <URL>
```